# Is there any production-ready way to check/enforce some kind of function purity in Java?

Tags: java, security

I'd like to have a set of classes (implementing some common interface) that may be user-defined. Classes (i.e. logic they provide) are pretty straightforward: some number of properties and a set of rules on creation of the new class instance based on the given instances:

```
class Example {
  private final int x;

  public Example resolve(final Example that) {
    return new Example(Math.min(this.x, that.x));
  }

  public Example(final int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}
```

Logic may be more complicated, but the principle is always the same.

When the instances of these classes are used by some server-side process, `resolve` method is evaluated and the result is used further. What I'm afraid of is something like this:

```
public Example resolve(final Example that) {
  deleteImportantStuff();
  stealPornSiteAccouts();
  return new Example(that.x);
}
```

So the when `resolve()` is evaluated, it leads to some nasty things. I'd like to be able to ensure that this can't happen during compilation (or in runtime, but that is less preferable).

Since I can't really know all the twists of users' minds, I can't know for sure what the implementation of the `resolve()` will contain, therefore I can't make any restrictions that will limit functionality in an unnecessary way, like limit possible package imports and so on, like it's done in Google's AppEngine.

The question is about purity checks, but in general I'd like to hear anything that might be helpful - lightweight sandboxing, function purity, syntactic restrictions, annotation preprocessors etc. How do I make execution of this kind of tasks safe?

To launch code in a sandbox looks like a right way to do it, but in the current process flow there might be *really* a lot of `resolve()` invocations which might turn out to be a performance problem, and a good performance is really a concern in my case, so I'd still prefer some way that provides means to do this statically.

P.S. I know that this might seem like a little too broad question, but since I want rather a guidance or a tip than a concrete piece of code, I hope the question won't be closed.

Comment: Use a `SecurityManager` to disallow dangerous operations?

Comment: @Kayaman, you should make that an answer. I can't believe I didn't think about it in the first place. (I frequently notice that Java's security framework is by far the most overlooked feature out there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) you can control access to resources like network, file and others. If it is clear that a class shouldn't be allowed to perform these potentially dangerous operations, you can disallow them for those untrusted classes.

Answer (score 0):

By giving your user's access to your code, they could do anything they want. Why is it so important that a user could write code into your system?

I think you should consider doing one of the following:

1. Remove the capability of allowing users to attempt to implement one of your interfaces.
2. Write your own "language" that will interpret and translate what they want to happen into java code. That way, you are forcing the user to a subset of commands. I have seen something like this done with just using XML and a schema to define it.

If you can limit the user to just input parameters or create some type of file that your software could dynamically recognize, I think that would be the better bet.

Comment: I'm sorry for being tautological, but in my case that is actually the case - I *intend* to allow them to execute their logic on my server.